# Fixing broken cast aluminum?

Tags: tools, powertools, aluminum, welding, cast-iron

My drill press was dropped and the table broke off. The break is shown in the picture. Nothing got bent out of shape the table part fits this break perfectly. Is there a reasonable way to re-attach the table?

[image]

Comment: I seriously doubt that is cast aluminum. The picture looks a lot more like cast iron due to the grey grain structure seen at the break.

Comment: BTW it is possible to re-join cast iron pieces using a brazing process which uses a flux and brass filler rod welded using an oxygen-acetylene gas torch. If you do not have such equipment or experience you may want to search out a welding shop.

Comment: is there room to run a bolt through the two pieces

Comment: Oh, but  you're not going to like it.  The only reliable way to weld cast iron (and it won't work with cheap slaggy Chinese iron) is to heat it to 1100 degrees over a day then to 1500 and weld it with special rod *inside the oven*, then do a very controlled day of cooldown.  On the other hand, this would cost about the same as 3 really nice drill presses.

Comment: Lets see the other piece????!!!!???

Comment: Big chunk of aluminum with a hole routed through it the right shape to fit tight, and lots of bolt holes or threaded holes. It'll be ugly, but it might work.

Comment: I'm surprised no one had complained about this being off topic since it's not about home repair or improvement.

Answer (score 1):

Is that the stanchion onto which the work table is hanging? If so, you are never going to get enough strength again to be useful. The moment of leverage for that is so far out there that any force pressing on the table is going to make any repair fail. I would suggest finding the mfr of the drill press and finding out how to buy a replacement part.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this as a comment but to long. I kinda agree with Harper I but just welded a cast iron part for our 75 ton press the part has to be hot as he said I used a large propane "weed burner" to heat the part up and used a stainless rod , after welding put it in our rod oven to cool down yes it took several hours when it got down to the temp of the rod oven I pulled it out and placed it on a insulating blanket it took another hour and a half to cool. 
There were a couple of small spider cracks but it is holding so far this part moves the press bed up and down and the bed weighs several hundred pounds the part that broke was the hoist housing so it is supporting all that weight when moving the bed until the pins are installed under the bed.
 So it can be done with a stick welder and stainless rod or if you want better results get some cast rod. I also ground out a v to provide better penetration but only went 1/2 way through on 1 side then a top pass on the other side.